# Keeping one weight measurement for participants with multiple measurements in R

Tags: r

So I am trying to figure out the best way to deal with this issue. I am working with a longitudinal dataset that has multiple weight measurements for each participant on the same day. What I want to do is to only keep the first observation (measurement) for each participant on that day. I am using R.
This is an example of how the data looks like.

```
ID     Date    Weight
1     2/1     160
1     2/1     159
1     2/1     160.5
2     2/1     200
2     2/1     198
2     2/1     201
```

I am not sure how to deal with this yet.
My expectation is to have the dataset look like this (only keeping the first observation)

```
ID     Date    Weight
1     2/1     160

2     2/1     200
```

Comment: Please don't post your example as images.  I rolledback to the original post

Answer (score 1):

We can use `slice_head` after grouping by 'ID' and 'Date'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID, Date) %>%
   slice_head(n = 1) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
     ID Date  Weight
  <int> <chr>  <dbl>
1     1 2/1      160
2     2 2/1      200
```

---

Or with `duplicated` in `base R`

```
df1[!duplicated(df1[c("ID", "Date")],]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Date = c("2/1", 
"2/1", "2/1", "2/1", "2/1", "2/1"), Weight = c(160, 159, 160.5, 
200, 198, 201)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like data.table (especially fast for large data sets) you could go with:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- as.data.table(df1)
df1[ , rowNum := seq_len(.N),  by = .(ID, Date)]
df1 <- df1[rowNum == 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `filter` combined with `row_number()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
  ungroup
```

```
     ID Date  Weight
  <int> <chr>  <dbl>
1     1 2/1      160
2     2 2/1      200
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to keep only the first measurement, use negated `duplicated`.

```
dat[!duplicated(dat$ID), ]
#   ID Date Weight
# 1  1  2/1    160
# 4  2  2/1    200
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Date = c("2/1", 
"2/1", "2/1", "2/1", "2/1", "2/1"), Weight = c(160, 159, 160.5, 
200, 198, 201)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```